# UILabel Truncation

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uilabel

I have text like this: "My text is blabla blabla, lala lala ".

I would like to have the text in my `UILabel` like this: "My text is ...lala".

How can I configure my `UILabel` to display the text to have the ellipsis in the middle?

Comment: UILineBreakModeMiddleTruncation

Comment: @JuanPabloBoeroAlvarez, your answer does not answer the question since this is tagged as Objective-C question, not a Swift question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The word you are looking for is "ellipsis" ;)

Set the following properties:

```
label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = false;
label.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingMiddle;
```

You can also set these properties in interface builder.

Example stolen from here:
[Getting UILabel to produce an ellipsis rather than shrinking the font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7725795/getting-uilabel-to-produce-an-ellipsis-rather-then-shrinking-the-font)

**UPDATE:**

This was deprecated in iOS 6. The current solution would be the slightly modified:

```
label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = NO;
label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingMiddle
```

Comment: thanks, were i can do : label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth= NO in Interface Builder ?

Comment: thanks, i was not clear in my question, the right one is : UILineBreakModeMiddleTruncation

Answer (score 0):

**@DerekTomes** answer in Swift 2.x:

```
label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = false
label.lineBreakMode = .ByTruncatingMiddle
```

Comment: There is no need to have the part before `.ByTruncatingMiddle`. It is redundant.

Comment: This fails to answer the question, given that it is for Swift 2 and the question is clearly tagged for Objective-C. Additionally, this adds no new information to the post since it is just a copy of the already accepted answer. Including the NSLineBreakMode is redundant regardless of experience level, as it is unneeded code.

Comment: @WMios thanks for your feedback, now the tag is added and the author was given its credit. Besides that we should let the community choose if this answer helps someone or not, your only criteria should not be used for that purpose, since you might be neglecting people the right to know, and totally misleading the purpose of the site.

Answer (score 0):

Try to select the label, then in attribute inspector set line break to truncate middle [image: image reference]