# How do I automatically truncate a UILabel on word boundaries with ellipsis?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, uilabel

I have a 1-line label that I want to truncate on word boundaries and add ellipsis (i.e. "The quick brown fox..." instead of "The quick brown fix jum...". Is there an easy way to achieve this? I've tried setting lineBreakMode to UILineBreakModeTailTruncation, UILineBreakModeWordWrap, and UILineBreakModeTailTruncation | UILineBreakModeWordWrap and none of these get the desired behavior. I've also tried their NSLineBreak... counterparts.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting UILabel to produce an ellipsis rather then shrinking the font](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7725795/getting-uilabel-to-produce-an-ellipsis-rather-then-shrinking-the-font)

Comment: No, not the same issue. UILineBreakModeTailTruncation truncates at character boundaries, not word boundaries. I already have font-shrinking off.

Comment: It's not "easy" but it's not that hard either to use the sizeWithFont methods in the NSString UIKit Additions.  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 3):

I got this working by customizing this [example](http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/truncate-an-nsstring-and-append-an-ellipsis-respecting-the-font-size.html).

My code uses `-[NSString enumerateSubstringsInRange:options:usingBlock:]` to find words, and then for each word found I check `-[NSString boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:]` to find if the string still fits my width limit. If the string up to latest found word goes over my limit, I'd use the last word found as the final word of my truncated string.

Just append ellipsis at the end of string and profit!