# How to make UILabel text appear with ellipsis at the end when text is longer than label's width

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, autolayout, uilabel

My issue is with a `UILabel`.

The text it holds is much longer than the actual width of the UILabel. So I would like it to appear with "..." (an ellipsis) at the end to denote that there's more text.

I played around with horizontal content hugging priority (made it less than 251) but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Right now it just chops the text when the width fills up.

Comment: Duplicate of [Getting UILabel to produce an ellipsis rather then shrinking the font](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7725795/getting-uilabel-to-produce-an-ellipsis-rather-then-shrinking-the-font) ?

Comment: @Polis Did you fix your issue ?

Comment: Yes thx! Problem was I had it set to multiline, now it shows

Comment: @Polis Happy you fixed it ! I upvoted your question ;)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is fairly easy:

1. Create a UILabel called "aLabel" for example.
2. Create an IBOutlet.
3. Do:

   ```
   aLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = false
   aLabel.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
   ```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I tried it but no effect. Still chops the text without an eclipse at the end. Could it be that I added a width auto-layout constraint to the UILabel?

Comment: @Polis This is extremely weird. When I create a UILabel and give it constraints, an ellipsis automatically appears if the text is too long. And I did add a width constraint. Please try recreating your UILabel :)

Answer (score 3):

If you are adding UIlabel through a Storyboard, following steps can be useful:

1. Select the **label** which you want to display '...' at the end.
2. Go to **attributes inspector**.
3. Select '**Line Breaks**' and choose an option **Truncate Tail**
4. Check it by giving a text of more content size than label size.

Answer (score 1):

Objective C:

```
yourUILabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = false;
yourUILabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;
```

Answer (score 1):

If your label is using `attributedText` or parsing HTML to string label you should add `self.messageContentLabel.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail` on the last code like this:

```
let convertedTextToAttributeText = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: customTextStyle.htmlToAttributedString)
self.messageContentLabel.attributedText = convertedTextToAttributeText
// Other line of code
self.messageContentLabel.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
```